# High Sierra Chat.db Timestamp

Tags: message, macos-high-sierra

I'm going to chat.db to get messages on a application (Mac OS).

Before Sierra in my SQL SELECT I was using `datetime(date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')` to convert the timestamps.

Now on High Sierra it's not working, I get nothing.

It's seems the timestamps change... more digit like this: `531651854330806016`

Does anybody know how to convert this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the exact error message you get? Trying your number and `datetime()` I get: *OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long*

Comment: no error, just return nothing ! I think apple change the format of the timestamp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Date fields are now nanosecond fields as per https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114168/dates-format-in-messages-chat-db

So you can try this:
`datetime(date/1000000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')`

Comment: It's working with datetime(date/1000000000+ strftime('%s','2001-01-01')

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS Mojave you need to add + 978307200:

```
datetime(date/1000000000 + 978307200,'unixepoch','localtime')
```

The last message time from iMessage: **2018-11-23 06:44**

```
SELECT datetime(date/1000000000 + 978307200,'unixepoch','localtime') FROM message ORDER BY ROWID desc limit 1;
```

Result:

```
2018-11-23 06:44:01
```